# How to delete objects present in array in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I want to delete a product present in wishlist array. The index zero item is deleted successfully but index one is not getting deleted.

[image: Image of Result]

When I try to delete index zero item I am getting wishlist Id, product Id, and index of that product but for the second one, I am not getting a wishlist Id.

### wishlist.html

```
<md-card class="md-whiteframe-3dp" ng-repeat="product in vm.rslt1" flex="40" style="max-width: 50%;">
<div layout="row" layout-align="end center"> 
  <md-button ng-click="deletePrdct(vm.rslt1[$index]._id, product.Product_Id, $index)" aria-label="Delete" class="md-icon-button md-mini">
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="/assets/icons/fonts/delete.svg" aria-label="Delete"></md-icon>
      <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">Remove from Wishlist</md-tooltip>
  </md-button>
</div>
<img ng-src="{{ product.Image }}" class="md-card-image" alt="Image here" style="margin-left:80px">

<div style="margin-left:15px">
  <h2>&#8377;{{ product.Price }}</h2>
</div>

<div style="margin-left:15px">
  <h2>{{product.Product_name | characters:30}}</h2>
</div>

<md-card-content>
  <p align="justify" style="text-indent: 30px">
    {{ product.Description | characters:150}}
  </p>
</md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

### wishlistController.js

```
vm.showItems = function(id){
        vm.wishListId = id;
        $http({
            url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/getItemOfWishList',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {wID: vm.wishListId}
        }).success(function(res) {
            vm.rslt = res.result;
            //console.log(vm.rslt);
            vm.rslt1 = res.result1;
            console.log(vm.rslt1);
            vm.count = vm.rslt.length;
            if(vm.count == 0){
                vm.showMessage = true;
            } else {
                vm.rslt=res.result; 
                vm.showMessage = false; 
            }
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('here');
        });
    }


$scope.deletePrdct = function(wId, pId, rindex){
        //$scope.vm.rslt.splice(rindex, 1);

        console.log(wId);
        console.log(pId);
        console.log(rindex);

        var ifYesPressed = $window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        if(ifYesPressed === true){
            $http({
                url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/wishlistProductDelete',
                method: 'POST',
                data:{wishlistId: wId, productId: pId, userId:vm.uid}, 
            }).success(function(res) {
                console.log('deleted');
                //refresh();
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert('here');
            });

            var index = $scope.vm.rslt.indexOf(pId);
            $scope.vm.rslt.splice(rindex, 1);
        }
    }
```

### api.js

```
router.post('/getItemOfWishList', function(req,res){
    var wId = ObjectId(req.body.wID);
    //console.log(wId);
    var findwishlists = function(db, callback) {
        var cursor =db.collection('wishlists').find({_id:wId}).toArray(function(err, docs){
            //console.log(docs);
            if(err){  
                callback(new Error("Some problem"));
            }else{
                callback(null,docs);
            } 
        });
    };

    MongoClient.connect(config.database, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        findwishlists(db, function(err,docs) {
            db.close();
            for(var key in docs){
            var products = docs[0].productsInWishlists;     
            return res.json({result: products, result1: docs});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: could you provide us your deletePrdct function ?

Comment: I have added everything to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be here:

```
for(var key in docs){
            var products = docs[0].productsInWishlists;     
            return res.json({result: products, result1: docs});
            }
```

result1 contains the whole docs object.

result contains the productsInWishlists item of the first object of your docs array

Double check if this is what you want to accomplish.